# Trouble saving Django form: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'

Tags: python, django

I have a Django form where I'm trying to save user profile details.  My `UserProfile` has a many to many field, which I'm having trouble saving.  Here is my attempted view code:

```
@login_required
def updateProfile(request, uid):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

    """
    First, grab the existing user data out of the db.
    If it's not there, we'll create it, then fill in the blanks from user input on post.
    """
    requested_user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=uid)
    user_profile = None
    try:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user = requested_user)
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        default_skill_level = SkillLevel.objects.all()[0] # default value.
        user_profile = UserProfile(user = requested_user, skill_level = default_skill_level)
        user_profile.save()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance = user_profile)

        if form.is_valid() and (request.user.id == uid or request.user.is_superuser):
            obj = form.save(commit=False) # get just the object but don't commit it yet.
            obj.save() # finally save it.
            obj.save_m2m() # this is failing. UserProfile has no attribute save_m2m
            return index(request)
        else:
            print "Not authorized to do that! Implement real authorization someday."
            return index(request)

    else:
        profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=user_profile)
        context = {
            'user' : request.user,
            'form' : profile_form
        }
        return render(request, 'booker/profile.html', context)
```

On a POST, once the form is validated I'm able to save the basic object but afterwards saving the many to many fields fails with the given exception.  What is the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Example:

```
...
if formset.is_valid():
   items = formset.save(commit=False)
      for item in items:
          item.save()
      formset.save_m2m()
```

E:

Try this:

```
if form.is_valid() and (request.user.id == uid or request.user.is_superuser):
   obj = form.save(commit=False) # get just the object but don't commit it yet.
   obj.save() # finally save it.
   form.save_m2m()
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Iterating over the items doesn't seem to work.  ``'UserProfile' object is not iterable``

Answer (score 3):

The save_m2m() is only required if you have previously saved with commit=False. In your example the commit=False save does not appear to be necessary.

E.g. you could replace

```
obj = form.save(commit=False) # get just the object but don't commit it yet.
obj.save() # finally save it.
obj.save_m2m() # this is failing. UserProfile has no attribute save_m2m
```

With:

```
form.save()
```