# form multiselection - Cannot assign QuerySet, must be user instance

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm attempting to build a basic Job/To Do List. In the Job create form, I'm trying to add the ability for the "author" to assign additional personnel to the job via a multiple select field from a list of registered users.

So far, it seems to work via the admin form. But when I do the same on the "Job create page" I get the following ValueError:

Cannot assign "QuerySet [CustomUser: testuser1, CustomUser: testuser2]": "Job.personnel" must be a "CustomUser" instance.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong in the view, I've seen similar topics but those options either didn't work or I just didn't understand the solution (I'm very new to Django/Python in general).

Any help, or suggestions on how this could be better implemented, would be greatly appreciated!

The Job Model from the job app

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from user.models import CustomUser

class Job(models.Model):
    """A model for active jobs"""
    job_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser, 
        null=True, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        related_name = 'authors'
        )  
    personnel = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        null=True, 
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
        related_name = 'addition_personnel'
        )
    job_text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now=True) 
    close_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    #  Job status choices 
    OPEN = 'Open'
    CLOSED = 'Closed'
    JOB_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (OPEN, 'Open'),
        (CLOSED, 'Closed')
    )
    job_status = models.CharField(
        choices = JOB_STATUS_CHOICES,
        max_length = 10,
        null = True,
        blank = True,
        default = ''
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_title
```

The CustomUser Model from the user app

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    """ custom user model """
    Position = models.CharField(max_length=100, null='', blank = True)
```

The Form - uses ModelForm with ModelMultipleChoiceField

```
from django import forms
from .models import Job
from user.models import CustomUser


class JobCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Create new job form"""
    personnel_queryset = CustomUser.objects.all()
    personnel = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=personnel_queryset,  
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), 
        required=False
        )

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = [
            'job_title',
            'job_text',
            'close_date',
            'job_status',
            'personnel'
        ]
```

and the View snippet

```
def job_create(request):
    """Job create form view"""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = JobCreateForm(request.POST)
        personnel = CustomUser.objects.all()
        if form.is_valid():
            new_job = form.save(commit=False)
            new_job.author = request.user
            new_job.personnel = personnel
            new_job.save()  
            return redirect('job_detail', 
                            job_details_id=new_job.pk)
    #  if a GET (or any other mehtod) blank form is created
    else:
        form = JobCreateForm() 
    return render(request, 'jobs/job_create.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: Your `personnel` is a `ForeignKey` to a `CustomUser`, hence it indeed makes no sense to assign `job.personnel = personnel`. Furthermore the `job` variable is not defined in the first place here.

Comment: Thank you Willem for the response. I removed the, job.personnel = personnel part from the code. Still have the error but I take it the ForeignKey part is the issue in general?

Comment: you did exactly the same with `new_job.personnel = personnel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've sussed it/ just got it working.

I had a rethink about the relationship between personnel and jobs and changed it from Froeign key to many to many, as Jobs can have many personnel assigned to it and personnel can be assigned to many jobs.

From Jobs model.

```
...

personnel = models.ManyToManyField(CustomUser, blank=True)
...
```

Then using this [Trouble saving Django form: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'save_m2m'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352446/trouble-saving-django-form-userprofile-object-has-no-attribute-save-m2m)
and the topic on model forms and the save method from 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method.

I changed the view to:

```
def job_create(request):
    """Job creation view with form"""
    #  if this is a POST request we need to process the form data 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #  create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = JobCreateForm(request.POST)
        #  check whether form data is valid:
        personnel = CustomUser.objects.all()
        if form.is_valid():
            #  process the data in the form.cleaned_data as required
            # personnel_inst = CustomUser.objectss
            new_job = form.save(commit=False)
            new_job.author = request.user
            new_job.save()  
            form.save_m2m()
            return redirect('job_detail', job_details_id=new_job.pk)
    #  if a GET (or any other mehtod) blank form is created
    else:
        form = JobCreateForm() 
    return render(request, 'jobs/job_create.html', {'form':form})
```